# nfs and nfsd are not available in Mavericks

Tags: nfs

I find that there is no nfs and nfsd available on Mavericks. Does Apple remove it ?

P/S: I am trying to mount shared nfs drive in vagrant.

```
> which nfs
nfs not found
> which nfsd
nfsd not found
```

Comment: What version of which are you using the one I use which I thin is Apple's provides no output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I have nfsd. I didn't use it before, Mavericks don't remove it.

Check your $PATH variable.

Comment: can you help me with the output of `which nfsd`

Answer (score 1):

nfsd is in /sbin which won't be on the default path

Comment: is it `/usr/sbin` you are talking about ? There seem to be no nfsd there.

Comment: No /sbin the answer is correct for my OSX

Answer (score 0):

Are these your error messages?

```
nfsd[3493]: conflicting exports for /path/to/folder, 10.0.0.x

nfsd[3493]: exports:56: export option conflict for /path/to/folder
```

The solution is quite simple here, you just need to clear out the /etc/exports file and restart the nfsd service.

Here is the steps to solve it:

1. Go to your Console app, filter by nfds and see what paths are
   conflicting
2. Open the Terminal
3. Edit the /etc/exports | sudo vim /etc/exports
4. Remove the entries you want
5. Save and close the file
6. Restart nfsd service | sudo nfsd restart

Now you should not have any conflicts and errors appearing in **Console app**, if it still appears then look into your file /etc/exports file again to remove the remaining conflicts.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it is not this error. `nfs` and `nfsd` simply don't exist.